# Request timeouts due to register/unregister conflicts in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have installed asterisk 11.5.1, and I have Bria on iPhone as the sip client. username/passwords are set in sip.conf, and the default dialplan (used by the clients) is

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},20)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

I have two iphones, say A and B, and I attached to the running asterisk with `asterisk -rvvvv`. When I hit 'Register' button from A, I see

```
Registered SIP 'A' at ww.xx.yy.zz:mmmm
```

message on the asterisk cli. When I hit 'Register' button from B, I see

```
Registered SIP 'B' at aa.bb.cc.dd:nnnn
Unregistered SIP 'B'   <== HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

although I do not hit Unregister from client B. Besides, B seems registered at the client. From now on, any call from B results in 'request timeout'. And if I call B from A, I see 'subscriber absent' message on the asterisk cli.

Why is asterisk unregistering client B? Any suggestion?

**p.s.**: I see the following error in asterisk cli:

```
chan_sip.c:3905 __sip_xmit: sip_xmit of 0x7f7df4027b00 (len 622) to aa.bb.cc.dd:nnnn returned -2: Interrupted system call
```

**EDIT:** My sip.conf file is as following

```
[myConf](!)
        disallow=all
        allow=g729
        allow=gsm
        allow=g723
        allow=ulaw
        allow=ilbc
        directmedia=no
        host=dynamic
        dtmfmode=rfc2833
        context=default
        type=friend
        transport=tls,tcp
        qualify=4000
        nat=force_rport,comedia
        encryption=yes

[A](myConf)
        secret=AAAA
[B](myConf)
        secret=BBBB
```

Comment: Can you also share the information of each clients A and B in the sip.conf file? That would help to get a better overview.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact solution but I can point to where it may can be the problem.

The documentated part of the code from where you hit the problem in chan_sip.c says

```
 * \return length of transmitted message, XMIT_ERROR on know network failures -1 on other failures
```

In your case you fall on the other failures as Interrupted system call. That message led me to an open bug suspended due to lack of activity [here](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-21310). So my bid is that this error is more related to operating system than Asterisk itself.

My following question is, if you invert the order (first register B and then register A) is the last one who gets the error? If yes then you may start looking at the selinux or any other security tool that is killing the connection after is established. Otherwise you may need to update the bug and let the people from Asterisk fix the bug.

Let us know the result, is always nice to find posts with fixes :)

Comment: "if you invert the order (first register B and then register A) is the last one who gets the error?" No, it is always B. As additional information, B is connecting via 3G and hence no NAT in front of it. A is connecting via wi-fi, with 2 levels of nat in front of it.

Comment: That info makes the problem more interesting! I don't think you have a problem with NAT here, what I understand from the error and the bug, you get this unregistered due to a problem trying to open/stablish a TCP port, that causes the second phone to get disconnected. Can you try to use transport=udp? It can also be that the TCP connections are blocked by operator (not sure about that last statement)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need deal with NAT

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

OR you have check that your B can got message from asterisk and answer it correctly. More info can be got using sip debug

```
asterisk -r 
sip set debug on
```

Comment: B is connecting with 3G, so there is no NAT between the server and B.

Comment: 3G always have nat,sorry. Sometimes it is grey address nat, but still NAT. If one server use 3g wise solution will be use of vpn(openvpn for example)

Comment: Are you sure? Even if so, A&B both have the same configuration. Then how do you explain that A works with 2 level of NATs without any extra configuration?

Comment: IF A also have 3g, then question have no sence. Can be anything. Message you refer mean communication not correct. Can be NAT, can be firewall block. No way say with info provided. For sure will work via tunnel.